# Do I use a Wagtail form or a Django one?

Tags: django, forms, wagtail

I want to add a simple form to my Wagtail site, which will enable some users (with suitable permissions perhaps) to create a new page, outlining a game scenario. Just a title field and a rich-text field in other words.

Now I have read the docs at http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.10.1/reference/contrib/forms, which is close to what I need, except that the AbstractForm class or the like appears to be geared towards letting users design their own forms, which I do not want them to do. So the alternative is to use a standard Django form, as per the 'example' given at https://github.com/gasman/wagtail-form-example/commits/master. However I do not find that to be useful.

So my question is this: do I use a Wagtail form which (I presume) has the 'correct' page-handling code, or I do I somehow shoe-horn a Django form into my Wagtail site and hope that it integates well with the Wagtail stuff?

Alternatively, can I simply use the Wagtail form and prohibit users from modifying it?

---

On reflection, all I need to do (I think) is to define a new Page type! That will be a form of sorts, which I have confirmed by examining the source of a 'Create Event' page in the demo.

I still need a link/button to invoke an instance of the relevant model but that should not be a problem.

As I indicated earlier, this is largely due to ignorance of Wagtail on my part but somehow the usage is not that well explained, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend going with Wagtail forms, here is why;

- Great support out of the box, easy reporting on submissions and email alerts.
- Good docs surrounding building a view for the form page and response pages, plus you can add some nice things to the form_page model like an intro paragraph.
- Better page handling as you mentioned, no need to work around how to put the form page in your existing site structure.
- All the benefits of normal pages such as searching, revisions/drafts, existing and using existing views.

Even if you might only (as the super admin) create one form (Game Scenario) it would still be worth it.

The page that is created can be viewed by anyone that views your site (or has access to viewing that page via the page permissions).

You can also record the user that submitted the form by following the instructions here:

http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.10.1/reference/contrib/forms/customisation.html#custom-form-submission-model

Instructions on how to edit permissions, so that users with admin access cannot edit the form structure:

http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.10.1/topics/permissions.html

Additional Information

In reply to your questions/comments, for the sake of future viewers;

- **Submitted data storage
  All form submissions (aka responses) get stored in a form.** submissions table that comes as part of the Wagtail forms module. You can define your own form submissions table if you need to extend the basic functionality.
- **Why there is not a page wrapper for Django forms?**
  I am not sure on this one, the main reason is probably to provide basic user defined forms as part of the Wagtail admin UI. Internally, Django form fields are used but defined dynamically on the fly and submissions stored as JSON. The purpose again is to have simple user defined forms.
- **Creating a Page Type.**
  Yes, this is how Wagtail approachesthe forms problem, a Form is just a page. This form page can exist anywhere you want it to in the page heiracy. This is different to Snippets for example, which are models used separately from Pages.
- Linking to Form Pages
  As each form page is also just a page, you can create a link to it anywhere you can link a Page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I still think that Wagtail could do with some improvement here. It is not clear to me just how the submitted data would be saved in a DB for example, or why there isn't a simple Page wrapper for a standard Django form. Part of the problem is that I am not that familiar with Django, let alone Wagtail!

Comment: Hey, been a while but I thought I would answer. Submitted data gets saved in a separate table with the model called FormSubmissions (assuming you follow the default instructions) in a json-ish field (Django does not support json fields for all dbs so it has to be generic text). There is not a simple wrapper because that would not allow easy user editing of forms within Wagtail's admin. Finally - if you need the power of Django forms, it is best to use it and not Wagtail forms. The docs explain that this feature is not intended to be a replacement of Django forms.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon the same choice and the wagtail documentation states:

> wagtailforms is not a replacement for Django’s form support. It is
>   designed as a way for page authors to build general-purpose data
>   collection forms without having to write code. If you intend to build
>   a form that assigns specific behaviour to individual fields (such as
>   creating user accounts), or needs a custom HTML layout, you will
>   almost certainly be better served by a standard Django form, where the
>   fields are fixed in code rather than defined on-the-fly by a page
>   author.

So it's really up to what you need.